# Shell script help

Tags: shell, scripting

I need help with two scripts I'm trying to make as one. There are two different ways to detect if there are issues with a bad NFS mount. One is if there is an issue, doing a `df` will hang and the other is the `df` works but there is are other issues with the mount which a `find (mount name) -type -d` will catch.

I'm trying to combine the scripts to catch both issues to where it runs the `find type -d` and if there is an issue, return an error. If the second NFS issue occurs and the find hangs, kill the find command after 2 seconds; run the second part of the script and if the NFS issue is occurring, then return an error. If neither type of NFS issue is occurring then return an OK.

```
MOUNTS="egrep -v '(^#)' /etc/fstab | grep nfs | awk '{print $2}'"
MOUNT_EXCLUDE=()
if [[ -z "${NFSdir}" ]] ; then
    echo "Please define a mount point to be checked"
    exit 3
fi

if [[ ! -d "${NFSdir}" ]] ; then
    echo "NFS CRITICAL: mount point ${NFSdir} status: stale"
    exit 2
fi


cat > "/tmp/.nfs" << EOF
#!/bin/sh
cd \$1 || { exit 2; }
exit 0;
EOF

chmod +x /tmp/.nfs

for i in ${NFSdir}; do
    CHECK="ps -ef | grep "/tmp/.nfs $i" | grep -v grep | wc -l"
    if [ $CHECK -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "NFS CRITICAL : Stale NFS mount point $i"
        exit $STATE_CRITICAL;
    else
        echo "NFS OK : NFS mount point $i status: healthy"
        exit $STATE_OK;
    fi
done
```

Comment: use `set -vx` to help debug your script. Lots of issues will be obvious when you inspect that output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The MOUNTS and MOUNT_EXCLUDE lines are immaterial to this script as shown.

You've not clearly identified where `${NFSdir}` is being set.

The first part of the script assumes `${NFSdir}` contains a single directory value; the second part (the loop) assumes it may contain several values. Maybe this doesn't matter since the loop unconditionally exits the script on the first iteration, but it isn't the clear, clean way to write it.

You create the script `/tmp/.nfs` but:

1. You don't execute it.
2. You don't delete it.
3. You don't allow for multiple concurrent executions of this script by making a per-process file name (such as `/tmp/.nfs.$$`).
4. It is not clear why you hide the script in the `/tmp` directory with the `.` prefix to the name.  It probably isn't a good idea.

Use:

```
tmpcmd=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/nfs.$$
trap "rm -f $tmpcmd; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

...rest of script - modified to use the generated script...

rm -f $tmpcmd
trap 0
```

This gives you the maximum chance of cleaning up the temporary script.

There is no `df` left in the script, whereas the question implies there should be one.  You should also look into the `timeout` command (though commands hung because NFS is not responding are generally very difficult to kill).

Comment: Johnathan,

You lost me in your response, NFSdir is to be defined command line. The .nfs script is used to cd to each dir and return a code of 0 or 2.

What does ...rest of script - modified to use the generated script... mean exactly? This way others can understand your solution

Comment: So `${NFSdir}` is set from `$1`? You create the '.nfs script'; you make it executable; but your code never executes it AFAICS. If you keep the '.nfs script', then before you actually create it, you set the trap; then you write the code which creates and uses it; then, before the very end, you remove the file and then cancel the trap (so your command can exit with a success status). This also assumes that you undo the `exit` statements in the body of the loop, or you have to remove the '.nsf script' and cancel the trap before the in-loop exits. It is hard to analyze an incomplete script.